# Annotations and methods can not be recognized in Resources.java

Tags: java, android

My Android App throws a ResourcesNotFoundException.

```
09-05 21:19:28.456 23667-23667/andi.chroeappclient W/ResourceType: No package identifier when getting value for resource number 0x00000001
09-05 21:19:28.456 23667-23667/andi.chroeappclient D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
09-05 21:19:28.461 23667-23667/andi.chroeappclient E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: andi.chroeappclient, PID: 23667
    android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0x1
        at android.content.res.Resources.getText(Resources.java:339)
        at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:5496)
        at andi.chroeappclient.TasksArrayAdapter.getView(TasksArrayAdapter.java:40)
        at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2365)
...
```

So I clicked Resources.java:339 and saw [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PeQGk.png).

TasksArrayAdapter.java:40 is        `viewHolder.textViewPoints.setText(task.getPoints());`

I tried `Invalid Caches / Restard`, `Sync Project with Gradle Files`, and `Clean and Rebuild Project` but none of it helped.

### How can I fix this?

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class TasksArrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Task> {
    public TasksArrayAdapter(@NonNull Context context, int resource, ArrayList<Task> arrayList) {
        super(context, resource);
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, @Nullable View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent) {
        Task task = getItem(position);
        ViewHolder viewHolder;

        if (convertView == null) {
            viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
            convertView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext())
                    .inflate(R.layout.element, parent, false);
            viewHolder.textViewName = convertView.findViewById(R.id.textViewName);
            viewHolder.textViewPoints = convertView.findViewById(R.id.textViewPoints);
            viewHolder.textViewCycle = convertView.findViewById(R.id.textViewCycle);
            convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
        } else {
            viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }


        viewHolder.textViewName.setText(task.getName());
        viewHolder.textViewPoints.setText(task.getPoints());
        viewHolder.textViewCycle.setText(task.getCycle());

        return convertView;
    }

    private static class ViewHolder {
        TextView textViewName;
        TextView textViewPoints;
        TextView textViewCycle;
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you post your TaskArrayAdapter class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just change this line

```
viewHolder.textViewPoints.setText(task.getPoints());
```

To

```
viewHolder.textViewPoints.setText(String.valueOf(task.getPoints()));
```

Comment: Oh man ... Sometimes it's the simplest solution you don't come to ... Thank you!